# How to print session variables in descending order?

Tags: php

I have a code:

```
<table>
                <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['cart']))
                foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $item){
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $item['num'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $item['name'] ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <img class="cart_remove" src="images/x.png" alt="" /><span class="item_index"><?php echo $key ?></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </table>
```

It prints session variables like:

```
1 name1
2 name2
3 name3
4 name4
```

But I need the latest added values print first. Like:

```
4 name4
3 name3
2 name2
1 name1
```

So, how can i print session variables in descending order? And also, is it possible to print, for example, latest 3 session variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the elements order:

```
krsort($_SESSION['cart']);
```

If you want to print the last 3 entries in `$_SESSION['cart']` specifically - you can do something like this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value)
{
    // do your other stuff here
    if (++$i === 3) break;
}
```

Comment: +1 and @Narf: It is safe to assume numeric keys considering it is called `$item['num']` :)

Comment: @anubhava: the example show numeric values, but they are not the *keys* of the array! the key is `$key`.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(array_reverse($_SESSION['cart'], true) as $key => $item) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: But won't this calculate the reversed array each time, and then the `foreach` will get into mess? I'm asking not noting, and I think storing the reversed array in a `temp` and then using it in the `foreach` will be safer.

Comment: This won't always print session variables in descending order because `4, name4` could be at position 2 in original array. @Narf's answer is one way of getting ascending order.

Comment: @anubhava: he prints them in order.. how the hell could it be at position 2??

Comment: Please read the question again. OP has just dumped all the `$_SESSION['cart']` values, there is no mention that he has **already ordered** those values in any order.

Comment: @anubhava: My interpretation of his post is different.. you see the `<td><?php echo $item['num'] ?></td>` parts? I think that's what he posted as an example...   ALso note that PHP arrays are *ordered*.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

```
if(isset($_SESSION['cart']))
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array_reverse($_SESSION['cart']);
```

Comment: this will reverse it on each page load

Comment: yeah right, didn't think about that. So reverse it to a temp array instead to the session itself.